# using where clause with Union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, t1 and t2, with identical columns(id, desc) and data. But one of the columns, desc, might have different data for the same primary key, id.

I want to select all those rows from these two tables such that t1.desc != t2.desc

```
select a.id, b.desc 
FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 AS a
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT * FROM t2 AS b)
WHERE a.desc != b.desc
```

For example, if t1 has (1,'aaa') and (2,'bbb') and t2 has(1,'aaa') and (2,'bbb1') then the new table should have (2,'bbb') and (2,'bbb1')

However, this does not seem to work. Please let me know where I am going wrong and what is the right way to do it right.

Comment: What is your RDBMs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION ALL` dumps all rows of the second part of the query *after* the rows produced by the first part of the query. You cannot compare `a`'s fields to `b`'s, because they belong to different rows.

What you are probably trying to do is locating records of `t1` with `id`s matching these of `t2`, but different description. This can be achieved by a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.id, b.desc
FROM t1 AS a
JOIN t2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.desc != b.desc
```

This way records of `t1` with IDs matching records of `t2` would end up on the same row of joined data, allowing you to do the comparison of descriptions for inequality.

> I want both the rows to be selected is the descriptions are not equal

You can use `UNION ALL` between two sets of rows obtained through join, with tables switching places, like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.desc -- t1 is a, t2 is b
FROM t1 AS a
JOIN t2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.desc != b.desc
    UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, b.desc -- t1 is b, t2 is a
FROM t2 AS a
JOIN t1 AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.desc != b.desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want both the rows to be selected if the descriptions are not equal. That is, the new table should have all the rows from both t1 and t2 whose descriptions differ. For example, if t1 has (1,'aaa') and (2,'bbb') and t2 has(1,'aaa') and (2,'bbb1') then the new table should have (2,'bbb') and (2,'bbb1'). Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 5):

`Union` is not going to compare the data.You need `Join` here

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 AS a 
inner join  t2 AS b
on a.id =b.id 
and a.desc != b.desc
```

Answer (score 2):

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types.

So, if it has same number of columns and same datatype, then use Union otherwise join only  Can be used.

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 AS a 
inner join  t2 AS b
on a.id =b.id 
and a.desc != b.desc
```

Comment: Please, edit your question with the query code, not an image. If you don't know hoe to format it, just give one blank line before and after the code and 4 spaces or a tab character before each line.